# Is there a name for an operator that removes as many edges as possible from a graph while maintaining its transitive closure?

Tags: graph-theory

Given an acyclic directed graph $G=(V,E)$, we can compute a graph $G'=(V,E')$ such that:

1. $E'\subseteq E$.
2. If $u$ is reachable from $v$ in $G$ then it is also reachable in $G'$.
3. Removing any edge from $E'$ would violate (2) and affect reachability.

> **Is there a name for the operation that given $G$ returns such $G'$?**

---

For example, if $G=(\{1,2,3\},\{(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)\})$ we get $G'=(\{1,2,3\},\{(1,2),(2,3)\})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [transitive reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction). For directed acyclic graphs, the transitive reduction is unique, and is the same as the "minimum equivalent graph" (more closely matching your definition), and is the same as the Hasse diagram of the reachability relation.

EDIT: I'm assuming $G$ is **finite** here - there is no transitive reduction for the graph on $\mathbb N\cup\{\infty\}$ with arcs $i\to j$ iff $i\leq j.$